# How to retrieve LinkingUri of a file in Sharepoint using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph, azure-ad-graph-api

I have been able to use the Graph API to query the list of items in a Sharepoint Item

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/d7689e2b-941a-4cd3-bb24-55cddee54294/items

However I would like to retrieve a specific property (LinkingUri) of a particular Item.

If I append the filter clause

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/d7689e2b-941a-4cd3-bb24-55cddee54294/items?$select=id,LinkingUri

it gives me the error Could not find a property named 'LinkingUri' on type 'microsoft.graph.listItem' even though this is a Sharepoint list item

I am aware that the same can be done in Sharepoint REST API using the below
https://abc.sharepoint.com/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Shared%20Documents/Somedoc.docx')/LinkingUri

However I would like to achieve the same using Graph API

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Microsoft Graph [`ListItem` resource](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/listitem) does not expose [`File.LinkingUrl` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.linkingurl). The *closest* available property it corresponds to is absolute file url, which you could retrieve via one of the following endpoints:

via `ListItem.webUrl` property:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/webUrl
```

or via `ListItem.fields` `EncodedAbsUrl` property:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}?expand=fields(select=EncodedAbsUrl)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding:

```
?expand=fields(select=Column1,Column2)
```

Comment: Expand only exposes related entities. It does not work in this case